# Where to write functions in Kotlin that will be used from other activities in Android?

Tags: android, kotlin

Here's my MainActivity:

**MainActivity.kt**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity()  {

...

}

fun becomeClickable(v: Button){
    v.alpha = 1f
    v.isClickable = true
}
```

I would like to use `becomeClickable()` in other activities. What is the best practice for doing that?

I previously had `becomeClickable()` as a `private` function inside `MainActivity` but removed the `private` keyword and moved the function outside of `MainActivity`.

Comment: Anywhere, wrap the function with `companion object`, then use `MainActivity.becomeClickable(button)`

Comment: you can make a interface and add this method in it and then implement the interface wherever you want "becomeClickable" method

Comment: I can help you with the code if you want

Comment: This method name isn't particularly good. It doesn't imply that the alpha is changed and not just actually clickability.

Answer (score 3):

Another Kotlin extension proposal would be to add the extension function to the button rather than activity. This will make the code more readable as the operation is really done on the button rather than the activity. In addition, the function will be available even in fragments and custom views if you decide to use them. You can create a file called `ButtonExtensions.kt` and add the following

```
fun Button.becomeClickable() {
  alpha = 1f
  isClickable = true
}
```

Now you can simply use this extension function anywhere in your activity/activities by writing `buttonVariable.becomeClickable()`

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Use Companion Object

```
class CommonUtils  {
companion object {

fun becomeClickable(v: Button){
v.alpha = 1f
v.isClickable = true
   }
  }
}
```

In MainActivity use like

```
CommmonUtils.becomeClickable(yourButton)
```

Answer (score 0):

Kotlin [Extensions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html) would be neat here.

Just append `becomeClickable` with `Activity.`

```
fun Activity.becomeClickable(v: Button){
    v.alpha = 1f
    v.isClickable = true
}
```

Now it is available across all activities. :)

Comment: While true, the other solution that makes it the extension function of the Button itself makes more sense from code organization standpoint.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce completely agreed.